# return to a view in ionic fire with push with a button

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

i am wondering how can i return from a third view to a first view where all views where fired with the methode navCtrl.push() in ionic 3.

let's say for exemple, we have those views: Home, View1, view 2 and view 3.
the navigation between home and view 1 is fired with navCtrl.setRoot(), and betweend view1 to view2 is fired with navCtrl.push and between view2 and view 3 is fired with navCtrl.push.

Now i need to go back to view1 from view 3 without leaving view2 and 3 in the cache.
thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use remove() to remove the amount of views that you want to "avoid" coming back, then you will be able to to use navCtrl.pop() to return to your HomePage, like this:

```
    this.navCtrl.remove(1, 1).then(() => {
        console.log('Going to my first page');
        this.navCtrl.pop();
    });
```

I tested it navigating in this way PageOne > PageTwo > PageThree and then came back to PageOne, if you want to add a fourth page you will have to increase the second parameter.

Ref: [Ionic Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#remove)

Comment: hey thank you for the help but using this it retruns me to page Home meanwhile i need to go to view 1.I tried changing index but it only returns from view 3 to view 2 or from view 3 to Home

Comment: Try executing this.navCtrl.getViews() inside a console.log() while you are in View3, and determine exactly what are the views that you want to remove, remember that the first parameter is the index where you will start removing and the second is the amount, in your case I think it could be this.navCtrl.remove(2, 2).